# How do I create a variable from database inquiry to change photo name

Tags: php, mysql, file, rename

I Hope someone can help me solve this problem I have. I have been working on it for days and so many similar questions and answers are over my head. I'm trying my best to figure it out. So far, I am getting close. I am totally new to some of this. I am trying to build a recipe site where people upload a photo along with their recipe. With each recipe submission a random number is assigned to their recipe. This is the number from the database I am trying to change their photo submitted photo name to so that it is associated with the recipe. I hope that is understandable. I'm trying to give as much info as I can so you can understand what I am trying to do. Thank You in advance for any help you can give me. I am 63 years old who is becoming hooked on PHP and MySQL. I have previously been working with HTML and CSS but love the things you can do with PHP and MySQL. This is what I have so far:

```php
$select = "SELECT * FROM VaRecipes ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;";
$result = $conn->query($select);
```

Doing this to show the image works great.

```html
<img src="../images/<?php while ($row = $result->fetch_object()){ echo $row->extra03; } ?>.jpg" />
```

The photo shows on the web page exactly as I want. I'm sure it's got to be a better way of doing it. I'm just a beginner with mySQL & PHP. But here's where I need a way to set a variable that I can use to rename and move the photo. What I have so far is:

```php
<?php rename("uploadedphotos/uploadedphotos.jpg","../images/new_name.jpg"); ?>
```

This example works partly. It renames the image and moves it to the correct folder but the renamed image is named:

```php
<?php while( = ()){ echo ; } ?>'.jpg
```

instead of the name it is supposed to be named which is a number from the database.

This is my first question here so Hi everyone! ~~Mark

Comment: Is the file in the folder named that way? Or in your html?

Comment: The .jpg was created by the code and is in another folder. I think that is what you are asking about.

Comment: Why do you have a single `<img>` tag that you're templating _every_ files' data into, instead of generating one `<img>` per image?

Answer (score 1):

this is all wrong...

When you query a database you get an array/object of results...

```
$select = "SELECT * FROM VaRecipes ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;";
$result = $conn->query($select);
```

Now you have your results that you can iterate...

```
<?php while ($row = $result->fetch_object()): ?>

// While in the level loop context we can utilize the current result..
<img src="../images/<?php echo {$row->imgPath}; ?>.jpg" /> // This prints the img html that will load the image

// Then we can do other stuff while int he loop...

<?php rename("uploadedphotos/uploadedphotos.jpg","../images/{$row->imgName}.jpg"); ?>

<? endwhile ?>;
```

To be honest i dont understand the concept...
TBH you should not be moving the picture in a view context but regardless...

You should be moving a variable pic from one dir to another..

rename("uploadedphotos/{$row->imgName}.jpg","../images/{$row->imgName}.jpg")

For whatever reason you are doing this you migth want to to move the image bofore rendering in

The resulting $row array data only you can know since you havnt shared it with us..

Comment: I am not sure what I am doing wrong. This is what thee resulting page shows.        
                                                                                                                                                                       Successful Connection to Database

fetch_object()): ?>  imgName}.jpg"); ?> ;

Comment: Ok, the photo that gets shown is named jpg.jpg and the photo that gets moved from uploadedphotos/uploadedphotos.jpg is renamed jpg.jpg. Any ideas why it is not using the number retrieved from the database? I'm thinking I am not querying correctly. The result should be coming from a column in the row named "extra03". I will play with it a while.

Comment: Yes, I didn't seem to explain it correctly. All your code works but it doesn't do what I needed. I'm sorry if I wasted your time and appreciate you helping me. Just to clarify things. I'm not worried about showing the phot. I can make that happen after the photo is moved and renamed. I think I have that part down. The problem is that I need to rename the uploadedphotos/uploadedphotos.jpg to a 10 digit number stored in the database under column extra03. The last entry made which is why it is desc limit 1.

Comment: Since the photo name is unknown to me when they upload it , it is automatically renamed uploadedphotos.jpg upon its submission. That way I know what the name of the photo is at that point. I have that working. Then I will rename that photo with the random number associated with that recipe that is stored under extra03. It may sound complicated but if I can rename the uploadedphotos.jpg then it will work for my purpose.

Comment: You should move the image when the uploading happens... in tte view context you will attempt to move it every time someone accesses the page... you can get the photo name when its uploaded via php $_FILES['name'] if its not recursive

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset($_FILES)) {
    $name = $_FILES['name']; // The name provided by your form
    $type = $_FILES['type']; // type of file uploaded
    $path = $_FILES['tmp_name']; // the temp location it is stored in
    $size = $_FILES['size']; // the size of it.
    $error = $_FILES['error']; // any errors occured

    $randomKey = bin2hex(random_bytes(16));

    rename($path,"../images/$randomKey.jpg");

    // save to database path => ../images/$randomKey.jpg
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After playing with it for a while I have exactly what I was looking for. Thank You Tourist for solving it for me.

```
<?php 
$select = "SELECT * FROM VaRecipes ORDER BY extra03 DESC LIMIT 1;";
$result = $conn->query($select);
?>

<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="en"> 
<head>
<title>Recipes</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php while ($row = $result->fetch_object()): ?>
<img src="../images/<?php echo $row->extra03; ?>.jpg" /> 
<?php rename("uploadedphotos/uploadedphotos.jpg","../images/<?php echo $row->extra03; ?>.jpg"); ?>

<?php endwhile ?>;

</body> 
</html>
```

This code along with the ones I have already allows the user to submit the recipe then associated photo in one shot while changing the photos name and moving it to its permanent directory all without anyone other than the user submitting the recipe. The recipe will appear on the website for anyone to see and search for with no additional work from me. I know many did not know exactly what I was after, it works and I am happy to be allowed to move on with the rest of the site. Thanks again everyone for your help. I love PHP and mySQL & StackOverflow!